# How to recover deleted records by mistake in Mysql

Tags: mysql, recovery

I am using Mysql.And by mistake I deleted very important info.Is there a way to recover or even to see the deleted info over a month ago?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27456/discussion-between-anahit-dev-and-marco).

Answer (score 6):

If it's MyISAM - no chance to recover w/o a backup.

If InnoDB - it depends.
InnoDB flags a record as deleted and keeps it in a page for a while. When a tree is rebalanced the deleted records are purged.

So whether you can undelete records depends on how much writes were done to the table after the delete.

Open InnoDB tablespace in a hexeditor and try to find the deleted records:

```
hexdump -c table.ibd
```

If table is relatively small I prefer `bvi` (it allows search by a string or a binary patter)

```
bvi table.ibd
```

So if you see the deleted records - it's recoverable.

Other place to look for deleted records is the binlog. If it's in a `row` format - the delete event will contain old and new values.

InnoDB redo log stores the changes, too. But definitely it won't keep them for a month.

To retrieve deleted records from an InnoDB page you can use a [MySQL data recovery tool](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb) . Recovery of deleted records is similar to recovery from corrupted tablespace. But in that case `c_parser` must be called with `-D` option that will dump deleted records only.

**DISLAIMER**: I'm an author of the tool

Answer (score 0):

For InnoDB tables, if binary logs are enabled, one could use:

`mysqlbinlog path_to_binary_log_file > query_log.sql`

If binary logs are not enabled, there is a recovery [tool](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/02/20/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-an-innodb-tablespace/) provided by Percona which may help.

Created a [script](https://github.com/VanagaS/mysql-innodb-autorecover) to automate the steps from the Percona tool which recovers the deleted rows (if exist) and provides SQL queries to load the data back into database.

Please note:

> The time between the deletion of rows and the database stop is
> crucial. If pages are reused you can’t recover the data.